# Google services ask for the keychain password on system startup

Tags: passwords, arch-linux, login, gnome, manjaro

Since I installed **gvfs-goa** and **gvfs-google**, every time I turn on my computer I am asked for the password to unlock the keychain.

How can I avoid being asked for my password each time I access the system?

I could remove the keychain password, but this I don't think would be a secure solution.

Update: the **gvfs-goa** and **gvfs-google** packages are used to display the data in **Google Drive** on **Nautilus**.

How can I make it ask for login credentials only if I try to access Google Drive with my file manager?

Comment: There are answers on that question that are not Chrome specific. Have you reviewed and tried them? Questions don't have to be precise duplicates, but the answers do.

Comment: Which answer would suit me? Mostly there are answers recommending reinstalling Google Chrome. Instead I want to be asked for login credentials only if I try to access Google Drive with my file manager.